# Converting double backslash into backslash used for escaping?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a javascript string that contains `\\n`. When this is displayed out to a webpage, it shows literally as `\n` (as expected). I used `text.replace(/\\n/g, '\n')` to get it to act as a newline (which is the desired format).

I'm trying to determine the best way to catch all such instances (including similar instances like tabs `\\t` -> `\t`).

Is there a way to use regex (can't determine how to copy the matched wildcard letter to use in the replacement string) or anything else?

Comment: looks like you need json.parse, but we need to see the whole thing to be sure. you can `str.replace(/\\\\(\w)/g,"\\$1")` too

Comment: You can't parameterize a special escape (short of using `eval` which you should avoid). Just hardcode all your cases `\n`, `\t` etc.

Comment: @dandavis Thanks, the json.parse method worked out in the end since the data was originally in json perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by dandavis in the comments in original post, JSON.parse() ended up working for me.
i.e. `text = JSON.parse(text);`

Answer (score 0):

Second answer, the first was wrong.

JavaScript works on a special way in this case.  [Read this for more details](http://roysharon.com/blog/44).

In your case it should be one of this ...

```
var JSCodeNewLine = "\u000A";
text.replace(/\\n/g, JSCodeNewLine);

var JSCodeCarriageReturnNewLine = "\u000D\u000A";
text.replace(/\\n/g, JSCodeCarriageReturnNewLine);
```

Comment: This is wrong. He wants to convert an actual backslash followed by the letter `n` into a newline. What you have proposed is a way to convert two actual backslashes followed by an `n` or `t` into a single backslash followed by the `n` or `t`.